# Eigenvalue proof

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, self-learning

How to prove the following relation:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
Au_i=\lambda_i u_i & \Rightarrow & A=\Sigma\lambda_iu_iu_i^T
\end{array}
$$

**My try:**

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lc}
Au_i=\lambda_i u_i & (1)\\
AU=U \Lambda & (2)\\
U^TAU=U^TU\Lambda=\Lambda & (3)\\
UU^TAUU^T=U\Lambda U^T & (4) \\
A=U\Lambda U^T  & (5)\\ 
A=\Sigma \lambda_i u_iu_i^T & (6)
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Is the mentioned proof correct?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What is $U$? Is it an orthogonal matrix? Give more details - I don't have the book that you are referencing and I bet others don't either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to state that $\{ u_i \in \mathbb{R}^n | i = 1, \ldots , n \}$ forms an orthonormal basis to justify that $U^TU=I$ and $UU^T=I$.

You might like to state explicitly the definition of $U$ and $\Lambda$ as well.

Name: Orthogonal Diagonalization.

Remark: Since you are able to write $A=U\Lambda U^T$, A is symmetric.